# Passing parameter for every request

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm using passport to authenticate my users, there is no problem about that. My issue consists to pass for each page requested
some demanded parameters.

There are some ways to accomplish it:

- Using `app.locals` to store variables, but it will be available for every user connected and
          unwanted informations will be shared, this is a risk.
- When render a page `res.render('some_page', { params });` you have to put these extra parameters
          for every request as well. `params` object will be modified before send it.

I'm using the second approach and to do it I made a global function like this:

```
GLOBAL.handleRes = function(req, data) {
    data.session = req.session;
    data.user = req.user;
    data.userToken = req.userToken;

    if (req.user && req.session) {
        data.session.user = req.user;
    }

    return data;
}
```

So, for each registered `route`, I have to use this `handleRes` to build up the final JSON that will be
send to the page.

Example:

```
app.get('/project/list', function(req, res, next) {
    // DO SOMETHING
    var pageJson = {
        ...
    }

    res.render('project_list.ejs', { handleRes(res, pageJson) });
};

app.get('/another/route', function(req, res, next) {
    // SAME STRUCTURE FROM ABOVE
    res.render('another_route.ejs', { handleRes(res, pageJson) });
}
```

It works, however I want to avoid this approch of `handleRes()` function and make Express automatically "complete" my json parameters for me. How can I
make it easier, less verbose and more elegant?

Thanks!

**## UPDATED ##**

Andreas helped me out and the solution is:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.user = null;
    res.locals.session = null;
    res.locals.userToken = null;

    if (req.user)
        res.locals.user = req.user;

    if (req.session) {
        res.locals.session = req.session;
        if (req.user)
            res.locals.session.user = req.user;
    }

    if (req.userToken)
        res.locals.userToken = req.userToken;

    next();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common and AFAIK the best way is to put a middleware before the routes, where you set default properties on `res.locals`. Express will automatically extend this object (and also extend app.locals if anything's set there) with any data sent with to `res.render()`. For example:

```
// Put this before app.use(app.router) or any routes
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals = {
    one: 1,
    two: 2
  };

  next();
});

// ...

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('view', {
    two: 3
  });
  // Will render the view with { one: 1, two: 3 }
});
```

Comment: I was considering to use middleware before, but I was not sure how to make it Works. I figured something about route interceptor as well. Thanks